# Make Particles Point Towards the Camera?

Tags: particles

How can I make all the particles in a particle system face the camera?

[image: Screenshot of particle system]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a particle system with the following settings.I also made a short [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8zu6dyQkr2Q&featura=youtu.be) demonstrating the effect.

[image: Billboards always face you]

Comment: How do you achieve this in 2.8? I can not find the "billboard" option.